# "sandbox" JS object methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function to provide a framework of methods that gets a applied to an existing HTML element. It basically looks like this:

```
var vd = function(tgt){
    this.init = function(){
        var html_structure = '\
            ...\
        ';
        tgt.html(html_structure);
        this.vdID = createHash();
        tgt.attr('data-vd-id', this.vdID);
    };

    ...

    this.init();
}
```

and gets instanciated like this:

```
ovd = new vd($('#container'));
```

In the middle of development I decided I want to "sandbox" (quotes because it doesn't relate to the widespread meaning of sandboxing in this case) the whole functionality of all methods and confine them to the element provided as `tgt` as there are several instances within a page whose event handlers must not collide. To avoid having to redundantly create object references to all participating elements inside of `tgt` I added a new function:

```
this.vdq = function(sel, get_sel) {
    var fullsel = '[data-vd-id="' + this.vdID + '"] ' + sel;
    return (get_sel == true) ? fullsel : $(fullsel);
};
```

Instead of selecting elements by $(selector) I do it by this.vdq(selector). However I'm aware that this is neither an elegant nor an efficient (in terms of performance => DOM parsing) solution, especially since I have a rather large amount of event listeners that also rely on this functionality.

### My questions

Is there a common name/description for what I'm trying to accomplish here?

What is common practice when dealing with this requirement?

Am I missing an fast and easy solution here?

Appreciate any input!